# How to remove unnecessary Installer files from Microsoft Office Installer?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, windows-installer, infopath

I am trying to deploy Microsoft InfoPath 2013 using SCCM. InfoPath was only ever included in the MSOffice 2013 installer, not as a standalone. (I think there is a 365 standalone now days, but we don't use 365).

Since I don't need the entire installer for Word, excel, powerpoint, etc.. Is there a way to delete unnecessary installer files and .msp files so that I can save some space? (the entire installer is around 3GB and it doesnt need to be.

Answer (score 0):

The Office 2013 Pro Plus installer files in the ISO are less than 800MB in total. What is causing your Office installer to be so large? Maybe you could list of the files and sizes to explain.

There won't be a way to shrink the Office Suite installer that I am aware of. The installer only allows you to customize the features that are installed (i.e., which of the products in the suite are you installing), such as with the Office Customization Tool: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179043.aspx.

Also, if you are using the network installation point, this reduces the need for all the installer files to be copied to the client.